# Are there easy ways to convert an image to a cartoon achieving a high quality?

Tags: gimp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it easy to convert an image to a cartoon with high quality?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/is-it-easy-to-convert-an-image-to-a-cartoon-with-high-quality)

Is there some *relatively easy* way to convert an image to a cartoon with a high quality ? [This example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMIn4.jpg) shows what I would like to achieve.

I've watched [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNBDcUUDGLM) but the quality of the outcome is still far away from the one above.

Is there a way to make a better one (as close to the picture as above) ?

Comment: Oh really ? I'm sorry. I'm new here.

Comment: No problem. It can be migrated by a moderator. Sit tight. :)